# Flash Session is not working in Laravel 5.2.39

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am redirecting to a route from controller using code below but it doesn't work. The view could not get the value from the session.

**GameController**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('game.index');
}

public function sync(){
    return redirect('/game')->with('status','[SUCCESS]');
}
```

**View**

```
{{ session('status') }}
        @if(session('status'))
            asdasd
            @if(session('status') === '[SUCCESS]')
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">Synced successfully!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @elseif(session('status') === '[FAILED]')
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">Sync failed!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif
```

I have run `php artisan route:list` and the result is shown below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCyzG.png)

Here is my **route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/game', 'GameController@index');
Route::get('/game/sync', 'GameController@sync');
```

EDIT

Tried to run this route

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    Session::put('status', 'Just a test');
    dd(Session::all());
});
```

Result

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "9ZvL7FTzFt05rYXPviqhizohfFC6KWGqwMJVgYid"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "status" => "Just a test"
]
```

Comment: Is that your entire `route.php` file? That problem happens if you wrap your routes with the `web` middleware, considering the Laravel version you are using. From your route screenshot I assume you're not using it.

Comment: I put the route outside of web middleware since I read somewhere that 5.2 already have web middleware included by default. @TiagoRL

Comment: That is correct. Laravel 5.2.29 and after have this middleware already included. Your code looks correct. What `GameController@index` returns? A view like: `return view('myView');` or does it return another `redirect()`? The controller code you posted, is it from `GameController` or `HomeController`, what route?

Comment: @TiagoRL see edited question for full code

Comment: what happing when redirecting page ? you get error or just in view you can not get 'status' field from session ?

Comment: Have you tried using `Session::flash('key', 'value');`? Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#flash-data
If it still doesn't work, try to create a closure route just for testing purposes, and try to send anything over the session and print it out in your view.

Comment: Also, just to be sure, clear your cookies and session variables before.

Comment: @TiagoRL I don't get error from redirecting page. It's just the value of 'status' could not be retrieved.

Comment: `Session::flash('key', 'value');` have exactly same result and closure route too. The view can't get any value sent through session. How do you clear session variables?

Comment: You can see the session vars in the developer tools in your browser. Let's check if your Session is working at all. Create this route in your `routes.php`: http://pastebin.com/UhdhnUMd
It should return an array, where one element is `"status" => "Just a test"`. Check if that works or throws an error. How's the `sync()` method being called? Ajax? A link?

Comment: @TiagoRL see edited question for the result. An array returned when I tried to access route you provided. And I call sync by a link. No AJAX is involved.

Comment: Good, then your sessions are working. Now, adding to the previous test, this should output the session var when you access `page` route. http://pastebin.com/Wiev1Jbn
If that works, there is a chance that you've used `session('status')` in the wrong view. Your view structure has to be `<laravel-root>/resources/views/game/index.blade.php`

Comment: It did return the session value. I have updated the question with my content of `/game/index.blade.php`.

Comment: @TiagoRL is it possible because i use `redirect()`? When i tried to set session on `index()`, the view can get the value.

Comment: The redirect should work as you can see in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: Check the code in my answer, see if you find something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently something wrong with my enviroment setting. So I reinstall everything from scratch and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted I created a new Laravel project with the same version, 5.2.39.

Here is the full, working code.

**php artisan route:list**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI       | Name | Action                                    | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /         |      | Closure                                   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | game      |      | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@index | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | game/sync |      | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@sync  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home      |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index | web        |
+--------+----------+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

**GameController.php**

```
// GameController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class GameController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return view('game.index');
    }

    public function sync() {
        return redirect('/game')->with('status','[SUCCESS]');
    }
}
```

**resources/views/game/index.blade.php**

```
    {{ session('status') }}
    @if(session('status'))
        asdasd
        @if(session('status') === '[SUCCESS]')
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">Synced successfully!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @elseif(session('status') === '[FAILED]')
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">Sync failed!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endif
```

Then, I go to `/game/sync` in the browser.

**Output:**

```
[SUCCESS] asdasd
Synced successfully!
```

Comment: I am using laravel/homestead for my enviroment. What are you using?

Comment: The same environment.

Comment: I guess I will try to reinstall my enviroment and try again. I will update the result here later

Comment: I reinstalled and all working fine now. Seems like something wrong with my enviroment. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. But glad it worked out in the end.